# HTML/JS Make <select> reach bottom of window

Tags: html, resize, controls

Another simple JS/HTML problem. How do I make a HTML element stretch to the bottom of the page always?

I tried doing `height: 100%;` but it stretches off of the bottom of the page (since it's not located at the top, I think.)

What's the preferred method of doing this? If you resize the window, it should make its bottom reach the window bottom.

Comment: try putting position: fixed in the css of the html element that contains the one you want to stretch

Answer (score 0):

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
top:0;
```

if your element not is body, use

```
position:relative
```

on parent, and specific width, and height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bBhUX/

Add

```
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;
```

into the parent container

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position:absolute; //or fixed if you want it to remain at constant position even when scrolled
bottom: 0;
```